# Unable to access SharePoint site through internet (http)

Tags: http, iis, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint site (http) hosted in IIS and it works fine on the intranet but when accessing through internet the prompt to key in the credentials keeps on popping and user is unable to login. I tried the suggestions mentioned here but those didn't help.

http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.sg/2013/10/sharepoint-site-is-prompting.html

Also I tried to add the website to "trusted sites" as mentioned in some of the links but that also didn't help.

So I enabled the https and now I am able to access through the internet but this way the app using the web services and SharePoint csom fails because of invalid certificate. Please know that I am aware of the workaround to ignore the invalid cert but that will require the code change in the whole app and I am not in position to do that.

My question is what else can I try and is there a way to access a SharePoint site by HTTP through the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered [obtaining a valid SSL certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/)?

Comment: @Thriggle sorry forgot to mention that this is a UAT server and not an actual production server.